# How to build a web project with existing sources without Tomcat in Netbeans?

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

**How do I build a WAR file from existing Java web project sources without a local Tomcat installation in Netbeans 13?**

I have received an old Java Web project for Tomcat and I need to do a small code change and build a WAR file. The instructions in the project readme file are straightforward:

- File->New Project
- Java Web->Web application with Existing Sources
- Choose the source folder & Next, Next, Finish

However, the instructions seem to be coming from older Netbeans (version 8).
I have Netbeans 13.

At first, I got stuck because there is no "Java Web" at the Categories root. There is only Java with Ant (my project doesn't even have ant build files), and it has Java Web->Web application with Existing Sources under it. I filled in all the paths, so far so good.

But then I got stuck at this window where it asks for server settings. I don't want Netbeans to connect to any server immediately, I just need to build a WAR, and then I'll deploy it to remote Tomcat manually. From older Oracle documentation, this step should be optional but I cannot skip it. Is it really mandatory?

[image: Netbeans server settings]

Comment: What kind of web project do you have if it is not Ant? Maven? Gradle? Was it even created under an earlier release of NetBeans? Also, I just tried what you are doing on NB13, and yes, it does seem to be mandatory to provide an existing target server for your application.

Comment: Perhaps the reason it forces you to specify a server is that it may customize the build according to the target server, but of course that in itself shouldn't require that the server actually exists. How about trying the **File > Import Project...** approach instead? That's more accurately reflects what you are actually doing anyway, right?

Comment: @skomisa The only build file I have in the repository is nbbuild.xml, but it seems to be mostly empty, as generated by Netbeans by default and never modified. But I downloaded and extracted Tomcat and pointed Netbeans to the Tomcat folder, and it seemed to work fine, I was able to build war even though Tomcat itself was not being used at all. Import project offers only Eclipse and ZIP, which are not applicable to this project - no Eclipse related files.